# Unable to redirect to another URL through JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So, I made a simple page where the submit button should redirect to another URL. Here's my code.

HTML:

```
<form onsubmit="javascript:redirectRoll();">
            <input type="text" id="key" name="Roll" placeholder="Enter the full Roll No" size="60" pattern=".{10,}"   required title="Every Roll No is exactly of 10 characters" maxlength="10" autofocus required><br></span></input><br>
            <input type="submit" name="submit"></input>
            </form>
```

JS

```
function redirectRoll(){
window.location.href="www.example.com";
}
```

Whenever I click on Submit it just takes me back to the same page. Help, please!

Ok, I'm posting the link to the website I've just hosted:
jbresults.site88.net/results.html

this should make it easy for you guys to find the problem :)

Comment: `location.href` setting is ignored while a call to a server is pending. Use input element type of button and a click handler.

Answer (score 1):

As @teemu has commented, the form submission is overriding the redirect.  You need to use the following code for your `redirectRoll` function.  Make sure to change the `onsubmit` value to `"redirectRoll(event)"`

```
function redirectRoll(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    location.href = "example.com";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This work for me :

```
 function redirectRoll(){
    window.location ="www.example.com";
}
```

you may change the way you are calling the function 
in the html

```
<form>
        <input type="text" id="key" name="Roll" placeholder="Enter the full Roll No" size="60" pattern=".{10,}"   required title="Every Roll No is exactly of 10 characters" maxlength="10" autofocus required><br></span></input><br>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" onclick="redirectRoll();"></input>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try this

```
function redirectRoll()
{
    $(location).attr('href','www.example.com');
}
```